# why is my list not adding my option menu values?

Tags: python-3.x, list, tkinter, drop-down-menu, append

need a small pointer.  I am not seeing where is my error at.  I am trying to take all the values of a option menu into a list and do something with that list after.  For now, i am not getting the values into the list properly.  it just prints ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'] even if i change the value of the option menu.  thank you for your assitance.

```
"mulitple drop down list in a for loop"""

import tkinter as tk

optionList=['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
drop_downs=[]

class Application(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="ivory2", bd=2,     
        relief=tk.RAISED)   
        self.parent = parent
        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):
        self.grid()

        for i in range(6):
            self.Var=tk.StringVar()
            self.Var.set(optionList[0])
            self.dropMenu=tk.OptionMenu(self, self.Var, *optionList)
            self.dropMenu.config(width=7)
            self.dropMenu.pack()
            drop_downs.append(self.Var.get())

        self.get=tk.Button(self, text="print", command=self.final)
        self.get.pack()
        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)


    def final(self):
        print (drop_downs)

def main():

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("class basic window")
    root.geometry("250x350")
    root.config(background="LightBlue4")
    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Your default value in self.Var.set(optionList[0]) is set to 0 and you append it to drop_downs.append(self.Var.get()) before you choose any options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you append to the list the default value that you set before.

You should save your string variable in a list.

Like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="ivory2", bd=2,     
        relief=tk.RAISED)   
        self.parent = parent
        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        self.optionList=['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
        self.drop_downs=[]
        self.VarList = []
        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):
        self.grid()
        for i in range(6):
            self.Var=tk.StringVar()
            self.Var.set(self.optionList[0])
            self.dropMenu=tk.OptionMenu(self, self.Var, *self.optionList)
            self.dropMenu.config(width=7)
            self.dropMenu.pack()
            self.VarList.append(self.Var)
            #drop_downs.append(self.Var.get())

        self.get=tk.Button(self, text="print", command=self.final)
        self.get.pack()
        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

    def final(self):
        for i in self.VarList:
            self.drop_downs.append(i.get())
        print (self.drop_downs)


def main():

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("class basic window")
    root.geometry("250x350")
    root.config(background="LightBlue4")
    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: thank you for your help.  I suspected the problem was adding the elements in the wrong stage, but i didn't know how to code it.  your solution work and now I am able to tackle the next part of my program.  thanks again.